# Regex Find & Replace LowercaseUppercase

Tags: regex, replace, coda

I'm looking to find and replace "agoWhen" with:

"ago`\n`When"

I can find with `[a-z][A-Z]`, but how do I replace with a line break?

Comment: What programming language / software are you using?

Comment: This is to fix a large plain text document in the macOS app Coda.

Comment: Not sure about coda, But Typical regex:`([a-z])([A-Z])` replacement: `$1\n$2`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use regex to find the pattern and then apply for loops to get the desired format.

```
def insert_new_line(text):
    result = []
    for match in re.findall('[a-z]+[A-Z][a-z]+', text):
        for index in range(len((match))):
            if match[index].isupper():
                result.append(match[:index]+'\n' +match[index:])
    #return resresult
    return ' '.join(result)
```

For example;

```
print(insert_new_line('thisMan is not inClass'))
```

returns;

```
this
Man in
Class
```

And if you want a list of all the matches returned, you could simply replace the return line of the function with;

```
return result
```

in which case;

```
print(insert_new_line('thisMan is not inClass'))
```

returns;

```
['this\nMan', 'in\nClass']
```

Let me know if this helps.